# Battery Percentage Recalculate (Not Calibration Reset)

Tags: battery, charging, android-device-manager, battery-history

When I'm busy and don't want to reboot, I put the android phone on charge and pull out the battery and put a charged battery in quickly (without reboot)

But the battery percentage level does not goes up immediately. (Of course,it goes up in 1% steps,whether charging or not)

How do I force the device to read the replacement battery percentage *immediately*,  without waiting for it to increment in 1% steps?

Comment: I edited your question to make it clear.  If this is not what you meant, please feel free to correct by editing it yourself

Comment: Thanx! It's very correct. That's what I want to say. And... Don't you have an idea for that question? I hope so, realy, realy...

Comment: unfortunately, I haven't a way and AFAIK reboot is required

Comment: ok... and thanx a lot for help. have a good day :)